# C++ что использовать для создания Metro apps приложения для Windows 8/8.1?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, jetbrains, metro

Собираюсь сделать приложение на C++ в стиле Metro apps для Windows 8/8.1. Посредством Clion от JetBrains. Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении копать, какие библиотеки использовать, подойдет ли win32 библиотека, может быть кто-нибудь профессионал в этом деле и подскажет книгу или статью. Я плохо сведую в этом вопросе но хочу разобраться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первое, если Вы хотите разрабатывать т.н. «metro» приложения, то сразу забываем про CLion — только Visual Studio. Почему? Потому что, CLion поддерживает 2 компилятора: gcc и clang. Ни тот, ни другой не умеют расширения [C++ /CX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX). Безусловно, можно использовать [WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh438466.aspx), но я не могу найти ни единого плюса от использования оной, а вот страданий с её использования, я полагаю, не мало.

Второе, почему Вы закладываетесь на Win8/8.1? Если уж начинать, то может лучше сразу с [UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Начать можно с [Создание приложения «Hello World» на C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cpp?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) , а дальше изучать и изучать. Это совершенно новая платформа, в которой старое, win32, API не работает. Изучать придётся много, но и ресурсов хватает. Правда книги всё больше по .NET, но их можно использовать для изучения, т.к. разницы с C++ будет не очень много — книги ведь по платформе, а API там унифицировано(правда в .NET некоторые вещи будут гораздо проще)

Comment: Так-то CLion использует CMake, который вполне себе поддерживает компилятор от MS. Но да, согласен, толку от этого мало.